# Magento 2 Migration Error (eav_attribute)

Tags: magento2, migration

I'm in the process of data migration, using the data migration tool.  I'm getting the following error. Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm migrating 1.9.2.4 to Magento 2.2.5.

```
2018-07-09 14:55:56][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: 
started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-07-09 14:55:56][ERROR]: Class fileattributes/attribute_backend_file does 
not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.backend_model for attribute_id=146
[2018-07-09 14:55:56][ERROR]: Class fileattributes/attribute_frontend_file 
does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.frontend_model for 
attribute_id=146
[2018-07-09 14:55:56][ERROR]: Class fileattributes/form_element_file does not 
exist but mentioned in: catalog_eav_attribute.frontend_input_renderer for 
attribute_id=146
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use class-map.xml.dist to fix this. Make a copy of the file "class-map.xml" and change in your config.xml to point to this one instead of the .dist one. Then (tag leave empty) Or ignore problematic attribute in eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist

E.g.:

```
<rename>
    <from>fileattributes/attribute_backend_file</from>
    <to></to>
</rename>
```

Comment: Yes can do, what you say if we can put in ignore field

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it, initially, I was getting the following errors:

> Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: backend_model. Error: Class fileattributes/attribute_backend_file is not mapped in record attribute_id=243
>
> Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: frontend_model. Error: Class fileattributes/attribute_frontend_file is not mapped in record attribute_id=243
>
> Incompatibility in data. Source document: catalog_eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input_renderer. Error: Class fileattributes/form_element_file is not mapped in record attribute_id=243

The fix was to:

```
1) Edit the file: vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist

2) Add the following under (<classmap xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../class-map.xsd">)

    <!-- Added by Heider -->
    <rename>
<from>fileattributes/attribute_backend_file</from>
            <to></to>
        </rename>
        <rename>
            <from>fileattributes/attribute_frontend_file</from>
            <to></to>
        </rename>
        <rename>
            <from>fileattributes/form_element_file</from>
            <to></to>
        </rename>
    
    <!-- Added by Heider -->
```

Save and re-run the script.

Regards
Heider

Comment: yes I think it will work, but how can we put this attribute in source -> ignore tage? So, it ignore this attribute.

Comment: Hi HaFiz, in my answer, I ignore "attribute_frontend_file" by mapping it into "", mainly because the system no longer needs it (old plugin), in your case, you can do exactly the same thing by using <from>YOUR_SOURCE</from><to></to> notice the "<to>" tag has nothing inside it, which means "ignore" in other words, hopefully this helps.